# Product CSV file with Header

Tags: csv, export, export-to-csv, sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible that, from the impex script, to have the header values not displayed as a comment?

I mean, instead of my eventual CSV looking like this:

```
# product_id|name|product_url
YG3243H|My Product|/products/my-product
...
```

To look like this:

```
product_id|name|product_url
YG3243H|My Product|/products/my-product
...
```

This would be a regular job so I really want to avoid doing any post-processing stuff. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! Using the [`includeExternalData`](https://download.hybris.com/api/5.4.0/commercesuite/de/hybris/platform/impex/jalo/ImpExReader.html#includeExternalDataMedia(de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExMedia,%20java.lang.String,%20char,%20int,%20int)) method of [`ImpexReader`](https://download.hybris.com/api/5.4.0/commercesuite/de/hybris/platform/impex/jalo/ImpExReader.html). You can also use it with a [`CSVReader`](https://download.hybris.com/api/5.4.0/commercesuite/de/hybris/platform/util/CSVReader.html) which is more customizable.

With both solutions you have the possibility to set a `linesToSkip` parameter. You can set it to `1` assuming your header is in the first line.

Don't forget to set `columnOffset` to `-1` if the first column contains data since impex normally starts in column 0, hence data usually start in column 1.

You may also want to set the `delimiter` parameter to `|` because default value is `;`.

---

### Import

**With CSVReader**

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];...
"#% CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( ImpExManager.class.getResourceAsStream(""myDataFile.csv""), ""utf-8"" );"
"#% impex.includeExternalData( reader, 1, -1 );"
```

---

**ImpexReader only**

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];...
"#% impex.includeExternalData(ImpExManager.class.getResourceAsStream(""myDataFile.csv""), ""utf-8"", ''|'', 1, -1 );"
```

---

### Export

You can't "uncomment" the header but you can skip it.

```
"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""file.csv"", false, 1, -1 );"
```

You can also do that from Java if you want, check the [Export API](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+API#ImpExAPI-ExportAPI).

`false` means the header is **NOT** written as a comment to the first line at the target data file

For more details check the [ImpEx API](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+API).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but this would be for "import" process only right?, is there any way to have this customization for the "export" process?

Comment: @julioarmandof Yes it was for import, I've edited for export. It might not be exactly what you want though...